# WP 3.1 upgrade breaks AutoFocus+ theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, jquery, upgrade, customization

I run WP for my photoblog [ShutterScape](http://inversekarma.in/photos/) using the awesome theme AutoFocus+. Recently, I upgraded to 3.1 and now, it refuses to show the featured images in the individual post pages. I am suspecting a jQuery conflict, as the Error Console shows this error.

```
Error: a.attributes is null
```

Can someone provide some pointers to fixing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an update [available](http://fthrwght.com/autofocus/).

Comment: I can't help but wonder why the Wordpress Updates section did not know that the update was available...